# C# Keithley IVI Measure is slow

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I'm using the Keithley 2100 digital multimeter to gather VAC readings for a piece of calibration software i'm writting. I've made a small test program to gather some data on Keithley's IVI Class Library that can be downloaded from their website.

I'm running a background worker which is gathering outputs from the multimeter, see code;

```
private void readButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // gather readings
        {
            if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {                
                address = Ke2100FunctionEnum.Ke2100FunctionACVolts;
                range = Double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                resolution = Double.Parse(textBox3.Text);

                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Task already enabled");
            }
        }
```

This is my gather reading button, it checks to make sure the background worker isn't busy, then runs the worker.

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {    
                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        ACResult = ke2100Device.Measure(address, range, resolution);
                        richTextBox1.Text += ACResult.ToString() + "\n";
                    }));

                if(backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                {
                    backgroundWorker1.Dispose();
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
```

It takes around a second for the `ke2100Device.Measure` function to process one reading, but in this time period the whole program becomes unresponsive, which I just can't have in my program. I've loaded up the task manager to see if any of my cores are on 100%, as it seems like quite an intensive function, but my usage is just fine.

I'm a little stumped on how to get fix this issue. I've commented out the `ke2100Device.Measure` function and just had the rich text box add random numbers, this works as expected with no unresponsiveness.

The only ideas I have just seem to be another way of doing the same thing... Coffee break!

-- Edit --

Updated code;

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                ACResult = ke2100Device.Measure(address, range, resolution);
                Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.Text += ACResult.ToString() + "\n"; }));

                if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
```

Though if I run this debug code to check my bgw;

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //ACResult = ke2100Device.Measure(address, range, resolution);
                Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.Text += 0 + "\n"; })); //ACResult.ToString()

                if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
```

Then I don't get any hangs, perhaps there is an actual issue with the `Measure` function? Could it be doing something I'm not fully realising or seeing?

Comment: Based on the updated code, I can't see any other possible reason other than the `Measure` method explicitly invoking its business on the UI thread or the thread on which it was created/initiated. But this would be very bizarre if it does.

Comment: I'll try initiating it within the background worker, hang on. - still the same issue. If the method was to explicitly invoke its self on the UI thread, is there a way to stop this from happening? Maybe making myself an actual second thread rather then a background worker?

Comment: Ok. I'm going to sepereate the whole dll from my form1, so I will create my own class which has some functions to measure etc, then when I make my object on the form I will put it in a thread. Standby!

Comment: My gut feeling is that there is something else going on, it doesn't make sense that the `Measure` function hangs the UI thread.

Comment: Reporting back, still the same issue... :/

Comment: If you replace the call to `Measure` with `Thread.Sleep(1000)`, does the program still hang?

Comment: Commented out the `Measure`, put the `Thread.Sleep(1000)` and no hang.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62658/discussion-between-johnathan-brown-and-rotem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. I went straight into the basics of how the device communicates with my laptop, and found out that it uses SCPI commands, so from this point I started making two really simple functions that creates a connection, and then sends a command to the multimeter.

After this point I realised that all commands being sent to the multimeter and back are done on the command line, which then lead me to believe that the command line and GUI thread are actually the same thread, which would explain why the whole program would hang when trying to read data from my device.

How did I fix this? Easily, I put my app on another thread before loading it up, see code!

```
    Thread applicationThread = new Thread(() => Application.Run(new Form1()));
    applicationThread.Start();
```

No more hanging! I hope this can help other people down the line. Thanks for the help guys and girls!

Answer (score 1):

The call to `Measure` should be outside of the `Invoke` action. Calling it inside the `Invoke` effectively runs it on the UI thread, rendering your background worker meaningless.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {    
        ACResult = ke2100Device.Measure(address, range, resolution);
        Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.Text += ACResult.ToString() + "\n"; }));

        if(backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            //backgroundWorker1.Dispose(); // I don't think you want this here!
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not know that, I thought invoking it within the background worker was to make sure that it would only be run on that thread, in a way telling it this thread only. 

The Measure just makes the whole program hand for a second, whenever it is inside or outside the invoke. Thanks though (My coffee was great by the way!)

Comment: `Invoke` is a method of the form or control in which this method resides, and relates to thread on which that control was created.

Comment: Got you. E.G. needing to update the rich text box on the UI thread as that is where it is. My blunda! Thanks for the little comment on the `.Dispose`, moved that now. 

Though, the program still has that 1 second hang when gathering  data from the multimeter.

Comment: @JohnathanBrown That seems unlikely if the call to `Measure` is not running on the UI thread. Can you post the updated code?

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

As you want to notify of the state on each measure you probably want to use the the `ProgressChanged()` event that the BackgroundWorker exposes.  You can set the UserState property when you call `ReportProgress()`.

Doing this will mean you don't have to think about whether to call `Invoke()` or not as the BackgroundWorker will hide this implementation detail for you.

Also, if you update your GUI every 10ms i.e. 100 times per second you user probably won't be able to notice the different updates.  You might want to change this value to be configurable and then play with it to get the desired refresh rate.

Comment: Okay i've changed my code and I'm not using any invokes, instead my rich text box is being updated in the `progressChanged` but my program is still having that one second hang. I don't quite understand why the `Measure` function is making my program unresponsive for exactly a second.